# Multiple timestamps for various states in TODO lists

Tags: org-mode, todo

I'm finding `TODO` lists in org-mode incredibly useful. For example, say I have a task to send an email, I define the following sequence in my `init.el` file:

```
;; Sequence in TODO list
(setq org-todo-keywords
      '((sequence "EMAIL" "SENT" "|" "RESPONSE" "CANCELLED")))
```

Once the email is sent, I switch it from `EMAIL` to `SENT` and then to `RESPONSE` when I get an email back. Great! And I can timestamp the `RESPONSE` like so:

```
;; Timestamp on completed tasks 
(setq org-log-done 'time)
```

Now, I'd like to extend this further, so that I get a timestamp for `SENT`, which I can do by shifting `"|"` to the left of `SENT`. But when I toggle to `RESPONSE`, I don't get a new timestamp because the task is already closed.

Is there a way to get timestamps that persist for multiple states of a `TODO` list item (i.e., for both `SENT` and then `RESPONSE`)?

Comment: Do `C-h i g (org)Tracking TODO state changes RET` for the doc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of just rely on the done/not done state, you can specify for each task if you should record a timestamp on entering/leaving it. The relevant bit from `C-h v org-todo-keywords` is

> Each keyword may also specify if a timestamp or a note should be
> recorded when entering or leaving the state, by adding additional
> characters in the parenthesis after the keyword.  This looks like this:
> "WAIT(w@/!)".  "@" means to add a note (with time), "!" means to
> record only the time of the state change.  With X and Y being either
> "@" or "!", "X/Y" means use X when entering the state, and use
> Y when leaving the state if and only if the *target* state does not
> define X.  You may omit any of the fast-selection key or X or /Y,
> so WAIT(w@), WAIT(w/@) and WAIT(@/@) are all valid.

So

```
(setq org-todo-keywords
      '((sequence "EMAIL" "SENT(!)" "|" "RESPONSE(!)" "CANCELLED")))
```

Will record a timestamp when the state becomes `SENT` or `RESPONSE`